# How to monitor kid cleaniness after using toilet

Tags: practical-islam, taharah

How can a parent monitor that their children (kids) are cleaning themselves properly after relieving themselves as kids want to escape or lie about cleaning themselves and till what ages parent should monitor their kid's cleanliness?

Is there any book or hadith that can educate parents more?

Comment: Is it really necessary to consult a book for that? I mean the goal of taharah is to become as clean as possible. The steps to teach are clear: first you do it for the child, then you let the child try and do under instruction, once you think it does it well it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could monitor your child by looking at ur kids appearance, clothing, eating habits, the way he/she maintains his/her room and bathroom, how frequently he/she switches clothes and how he/she reacts when she sees an untidy place. If he/she ignores then, he/she is less keen on cleanliness but if he/she attempts to cleanup, then we could conclude that he/she is concerned on cleanliness.

You could refer the below site to teach them cleanliness: https://www.nbcnews.com/better/lifestyle/11-ways-teach-young-kids-value-cleaning-get-them-do-ncna1144321